# Remove Out of Bounds Warning on In Bounds Array Element

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a c++ function, that determines whether or not a rectangle can fit on a 10 by 10 board at pt `(x, y)`, with a width of `w` and a height of `h` .  There are 2 ways the rectangle will not fit on the board:

1. The rectangle would overlap with a already taken square on the board.
2. The rectangle would go out of the board.

The second bullet point is where the problem is. If I look for any points that would prevent the rectangle from working (point 1) it may result in a `out of bounds exception`. At first, I thought this would be quite easy to work around, just make sure `x + w < 10` and `y + h < 10`, and if they are, then do the checks for already taken points, and if they aren't, `return false`. The problem, is that nothing that I have tried has gotten around the big message saying that there were security issues, and the green underline in visual studio that tells me that it might be out of bounds.

Here is my current code:

```
bool canFit(int board[10][10], int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) 
        {
            int py = y + j;
            int px = x + i;
            if (px > 10 || py > 10) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (board[py][px] != 0) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

The code is really simple, and I can't see why it won't detect that it can not thow an out of bounds expection. The pop up is really annoying, and I do not want it in the consumer version.

Comment: `px = y + i` and the inverse for `py` certainly seems like a typo.

Comment: You fixed what I assumed to be a typo, which makes me want to ask: did you copy and paste your code directly from your IDE, or did you transcribe it here? Please provide a [example] along with sample input that causes your error.

Comment: `if (px > 10 || py > 10)` shouldn't `10` be `9` ? or `>=`

Comment: `int board[10][10]` - I personally would go with `std::array` instead. C-style arrays decay to pointers too easily and a `std::array` knows it's own size.

Comment: If `x` or `y` were negative you would get an out of bounds exception. Since they are parameters to your function the compiler has no way of knowing what the values might be,

Comment: @Tony Tannous  yep, that was the mistake, thanks .